# rsync fails after server restart

Tags: linux, rsync

Usually I use the command

```
rsync -av --delete someroot/somedir user@remote_server_ip:/someroot/.
```

on my development server to synchronize `somedir` to a remote server. It worked fine. But after the remote server was restarted this command does not work anymore. It displays the following error messages:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(463) [sender=2.6.8]
```

But the SSH service still works correctly. I can use `ssh user@server_ipaddress` to log in to the server. How can I make the `rsync` work again?

**update:**
 `rsync` also doesn't work locally. it gives error as follows:

```
[root@videochatweb1 web]# ./sync_client.sh
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/opt/web/client/index.php"     failed: Permission denied (13)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at main.c(892)    [sender=2.6.8]
```

**update 2**

I compiled the source code of  `rsync` and reinstall it on the server.Now it works.Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Can you run `rsync` on the remote system?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,I try rsync from the server to another server,it gives me some error like `rsync: Failed to exec ssh: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(83) [sender=2.6.8]
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(1119) [sender=2.6.8]
`

Comment: Does it work locally on that server?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,what do u mean locally?just run `rsync` alone?

Comment: Just rsync from one directory to another.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,yes,local transmission can be done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3066/discussion-between-spawnst-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Comment: Well, "Permission denied", it says: what are the permissions on the file in question? Add output of "`ls -l /opt/web/client/index.php`" to your question.

Comment: @Daniel Andersson,the file is in state `777`. And i ran the command using root.I've no idea why it said no permission..

Answer (score 1):

Since the error message says "error in rsync protocol", this indicates that rsync is using the `rsync` protocol for communication and *not* `ssh`. So your test that shows that `ssh` is working is immaterial, but can lead to a solution.

I think that the remote server may have been running rsync as a daemon (`rsync --daemon`) prior to reboot. It wasn't restarted automatically after reboot.

I see two solutions:

1. Restart `rsync --daemon` on the remote server. Put it into something in `/etc/init.d` or similar so that it restarts after the next reboot.
2. Use `ssh` protocol for rsync instead.

To use `ssh` for rsync, set the environment variable:

```
export RSYNC_RSH=ssh
```

or add `-e ssh` to your rsync command.

Comment: `rsync` on the local system talks to `rsync` on the remote system using the rsync protocol. ssh is only the transport.

Comment: `rsync --daemon` listens on port 873 (by default). This is independent of `ssh`

Comment: Daemon mode has nothing to do with the question. The default transport for `rsync` is ssh unless a double colon is used.

Comment: Ah... good point on the double colon. You're right about that. Modern `rsync` uses `ssh`, but I think older ones used `rsh` by default. I remember having to set RSYNC_RSH (and continue doing it out of habit and/or legacy bash startup files).

Comment: I've tried using `-e ssh` option but still got the same error.:(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, those rsync error codes are due to different versions of rsync between the client and server, can you check the version number of both ?

- What OS are you using both on the client and the server machine ?

Comment: All my servers are using CentOS release 5.2,and the `rsync --version` shows   `rsync  version 2.6.8  protocol version 29`.

Comment: My CentOS 5.8 servers shows rsync-3.0.6-4, so you are using an old version. I remember that rsync is one of the first things I need to update when the server was installed and the error message was similar as yours. Just to be sure, I would recommend update the openssh package as well. (yum update openssh rsync)